# ¿Ingresar String en array de una busqueda en un txt?

Tags: java

> Mi codigo me encuentra bien los viajes de acuerdo con los rango de
> fechas que hay, pero yo necesito que me los muestren en un jtable y no
> me los muestra, asi como lo tengo me muestra todos los viajes no los que buscos, no se que estoy
> haciendo mal, o si hay mas
>
> opociones........................................................................................................................................................

.

```
public boolean Buscarfecha(File archivo, String fecha1, String fecha2, JTable tb) {
        String[] palabra = null;

        boolean existe = false;
        // Esta variable actuará de contador de los viajes encontrados
        int numViajes = 0;

        String[] titulos = {"Vuelo identificación", "ID  Aerolinea",
            "Precio vuelo", "Fecha y hora salida",
            "Aeropuerto salida", "Fecha y hora llegada", "Aeropuerto llegada",
            "ID  Avion", "ID piloto 1", "ID piloto 2",
            "ID Servicio cliente 1", "ID Servicio cliente 2",
            "ID Servicio cliente 3"};
        DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);

        try {
            if (archivo.exists()) {
                BufferedReader leerArchivo = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(archivo));

                String lineaLeida;

                while ((lineaLeida = leerArchivo.readLine()) != null) {
                    palabra = lineaLeida.split(",");
                    // Aquí dijimos que en Index 3 y 6 tenemos las fechas.
                    existe = DentroDelRango(palabra[3], fecha1, fecha2)
                            || DentroDelRango(palabra[6], fecha1, fecha2);
                    // Si está dentro del Rango en este caso operamos
                    // contabilizando los viajes que encontramos.

                    if (existe) {
                        numViajes++;
                    }

                    String fila[] = {palabra[0], palabra[1], palabra[2], palabra[3]
                        + palabra[4], palabra[5], palabra[6] + palabra[7],
                        palabra[8], palabra[9], palabra[10],
                        palabra[11], palabra[12], palabra[13], palabra[14]};
                    modelo.addRow(fila);

                }
            }

            if (numViajes == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No hay viajes.");
            }

            tb.setModel(modelo);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Arrojó errores
        }

        return (numViajes != 0);
    }
```

Comment: Hola, no logro ver dónde está el problema.  ¿En qué parte del código deberían filtrarse los datos, incluyendo sólo aquellos que buscas?

Comment: En la parte donde el código encuentra los vuelos

Comment: me muestra todos los vuelos que estan en txt no los que encontro de acuerdo al rango,necesito que me muestre los que encontro, solo se que encuentra con el contador de vuelos pero no me los muestra en jtable